# Matlab matrix Row Manipulation?

Tags: matlab, matrix

If I have a matrix:

```
A = [ 1 2 
      3 4 
      5 6]
```

how do I create another matrix from that so that it is:

```
B = [ 3 4 
      5 6]
```

Basically, I just want to take the first row off of a matrix and assign the remaining to a new matrix. I tried:

```
B = A ([2,:],:)
```

but that didn't work... Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just a sidenote, if you want to select arbitrary rows, then do as follows: `B=A([1 3 5 8 10],:)`. This will select only 1st, 3rd, 5th, 8th and 10th row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close!

You can do like so:

```
B = A(2:end,:)
```

where you can use [end](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) to indicate the last column index of the array.